# privacy policy about in my application

Tags: console, apk, privacy-policy

Adding a privacy policy to your app's store listing helps provide transparency about how you treat sensitive user and device data.

The privacy policy must, together with any inapp disclosures, comprehensively disclose how your app collects, uses and shares user data, including the types of parties with whom it's shared. Google is unable to provide you with legal advice and you should consult your own legal representative.

For apps that request access to sensitive permissions or data (as defined in the user data policies D): You must link to a privacy policy on your app's store listing page and within your app. Make sure your privacy policy is available on an active URL. applies to your app, and specifically covers user privacy. 
my apk suspend periodic about privacy policy? please help me

Comment: my apk is webview application

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What do you mean exactly by "my apk supend periodic about privacy policy"? Furthermore, most people here in the community are not lawyers and if you have issues with your privacy policy, it might be worth contacting an actual lawyer. Cheers :)

Comment: my apk suspend because privacy policy, help me to build or add privacy policy on my apk?

Answer (score 1):

Again, I am not a lawyer. My answer is not legal advice and you should **always** contact a lawyer if you have serious legal issues.

That said, I use one of the free privacy policy generators that are out on the web. Just [google "free privacy policy generator"](https://www.google.de/search?newwindow=1&rlz=1C1CHBD_deDE771DE771&ei=UPR1W4SgGcvTsAeFppjYBw&q=free+privacy+policy+generator&oq=free+privacy+policy+generator&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i20i263k1j0i7i30k1l3j0l2j0i7i30k1l3j0i7i10i30k1.199988.202073.0.202322.9.9.0.0.0.0.294.1076.0j3j2.5.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..5.4.882...0i67k1j0i203k1j0i13k1.0.51DsftjKLpI) and plenty will pop up. However, there are a few caveats that you should be watching out for:

- Make sure that you use the generator of a reputable source. I personally use [this one](https://www.wbs-law.de/it-recht/datenschutzrecht/datenschutzerklaerung-generator/) in my projects which was developed by the german lawyers Wilde, Beuger & Solmecke, but unfortunately, it's only available in German.
- If you are offering your app in Europe, make sure that you get a GDPR-compliant generator (the one by Wilde, Beuger & Solmecke is GDPR-compliant)

From a technical point of view, the only thing that you need to do is make your privacy policy accessible to the user such that the user does not have to do more than one to two clicks to reveal your privacy policy.

Comment: yeah... i has used generator free privacy policy.. today i update n wait several hour my apk is release on playstore.. but,  just a few day my apk suspend again n removed from playstore.. i'm from Indonesian n my apk is apk web view